# How to refer to the celebration of the anniversary of the birth of someone who is deceased

Tags: idioms

I would like to translate an article title whose meaning is something along the lines:

> In Honor of XY on the Occasion of His Birthday/ A Tribute to XY on the Occasion of His 50th Birthday which *he has not lived to see*"

Meaning that the person actually died before he reached age 50. So the impulse for writing the article is his death, not birthday. Is there a phrase which would be used in English and sound naturally? The original text is in Czech language. What alternative formulation could be used to convey that the article is written "on the occasion of his death"?

Comment: I often find the conditional helpful when discussing "post-mortem" birthdays: "Today *would be* Mozart's 266th birthday *if he were still alive*." It's less necessary for the long-dead, like Mozart, and more helpful for the recently deceased, since someone might not have learned of their death, and find mention of "their birthday" confusing. Note, you're not writing "on the occasion of his death" if your writing is timed around the anniversary of his birth. Your writing may be prompted by or influenced by his death, but "on the occasion of" connects it to a calendar date.

Comment: Dear Andy Bonner, Thanks a lot.

Comment: I’ve given your question a descriptive title that will help anyone who can offer a suggestion recognize it. If you post other questions here you should take the trouble to do this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the adjective "late" before the person's name:

> In Honor of the **late** XY on the Occasion of His Birthday
>
> A Tribute to the **late** XY on the Occasion of His 50th Birthday

In this context, "late" comes before the person's name, and is used to identify this person as someone who is deceased. There seems to be some disagreement on time frames though.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/late) defines "late" as:

> living comparatively recently : now deceased —used of persons

Whereas the [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/late) dictionary simply states:

> used to refer to someone who has died

without specifying a relative time frame like "recently."

Two examples from USA Today show the varied usage of the word "late" that supports both definitions above:

- [Memorabilia, other items allegedly stolen from home of late NFL receiver Demaryius Thomas](https://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/nfl/broncos/2022/03/21/demaryius-thomas-items-allegedly-stolen-home-late-nfl-player/7121583001/)

  > The Georgia home of **late NFL wide receiver Demaryius Thomas** was broken into and three individuals were charged with criminal trespass, according to police documents obtained by USA TODAY Sports.
  >
  > Police arrived at Thomas' former residency in Roswell, Georgia, last Sunday morning, March 13, **three months after his death**

  This usage appears to support the Merriam-Webster definition, because the event in the article occurred three months after the person's death.
- [Kent Waldrep, TCU rusher paralyzed during a game against Alabama, dies at 67](https://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/ncaaf/2022/03/01/kent-waldrep-tcu-football-alabama-paul-bear-bryant/9334961002/)

  > **Late Alabama athletics director Mal Moore** made good on Bryant's wishes in 2005, informing Waldrep and his family of the scholarship offer while the Crimson Tide was in Dallas preparing for a Cotton Bowl appearance.

  This usage appears to support the Cambridge definition. The article was written in 2022, but refers to Mal Moore, [who died in 2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mal_Moore) — 9 years prior to the article being published.

Personally, I use "late" as a general purpose term to refer to someone who is dead without a time frame. I find that I use "late XY" in more formal circumstances, like events (especially in honor of that person).

Comment: Dear Greg Burghardt, Thanks a lot. For my purposes, the translation following your suggestion will do. Yet I am curious to learn whether it is possible to convey that the author dedicates the article to XY on the occasion of his 50th birthday which are XY's first posthumous birthday, meaning that XY has died at the age of 49 and did not live to experience his 50th birthday.

Comment: The Czech language uses a modifier (adjective) "nedožitý" preceding the expression "narozeniny (birthday)" conveying a meaning of "not lived through" (deceased before reaching a particular birthday). From the example in English, we only learn that it was prompted by the occasion of his 50.th birthday.

Comment: On the occasion of his 100th or any other significant anniversary, there can be another article commemorating this person... but the meaning I am hinting at is related to the author's untimely death and the fact he did not live through his 50th birthday. Therefore it is in some way similar to oubituary in the sense that it is an article published on the occasion of the FIRST POSTHUMOUS birthday and that it summarizes the carreer, scholarship and life of a person.

Comment: @David: can you clarify your comment?

Comment: @David: I must have been in a hurry. I corrected the mistakes. I apologize.

Comment: No problem. Easily done. I’ll scrub my comments.

Answer (score 1):

The following form of words signals to the English native speaker that one is not referring to the birthday of a living person. Instead of

> birthday

use

> on the anniversary of the birth

Then you can refer to the individual as “late” without it appearing a little odd.

> A tribute to the late XY on the occasion of the 50th anniversary of his birth

Comment: It appears that I am echoing the title of the question. In fact that was my edit of a quite different form of words, which made me think of the answer.

Comment: Dear David, thanks a lot for editing the question and taking time to answer it. Best wishes, AG

Comment: @AriGató — You are welcome. It was trying to reword your title that suggested a solution. The problem, I think, comes from the fact that commemorative celebrations usually take place sufficiently long after someone’s birth that it is obvious they are no longer alive. It strikes me in writing this (on my phone) that the word “commemoration” might be employed in this context. I’ll post later if I think of an alternative. If you eventually decide to use a suggestion from one of the answers you should “accept” it.